# UglifyJS plugin isn't minifying all chunks in Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

My Webpack configuration is:

```js
{ devtool: 'source-map',
  output: 
   { path: '/Users/apple/Desktop/WorkSpace/GitHub/Webpack-Boilerplate/dist',
     filename: '[name].bundle.js.[hash:8]',
     sourceMapFilename: '[name].bundle.map',
     publicPath: '/' },
  plugins: 
   [ OccurrenceOrderPlugin { preferEntry: undefined },
     DefinePlugin { definitions: [Object] },
     ProvidePlugin { definitions: {} },
     ExtractTextPlugin { filename: '[name].css', options: {}, id: 1 },
     CommonsChunkPlugin {
       chunkNames: 'vendors',
       filenameTemplate: 'vendors.bundle.js',
       minChunks: Infinity,
       selectedChunks: undefined,
       async: undefined,
       minSize: undefined,
       ident: '/Users/apple/Desktop/WorkSpace/GitHub/Webpack-Boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin.js0' },
     HtmlWebpackPlugin { options: [Object] },
     HtmlWebpackPlugin { options: [Object] },
     HtmlWebpackPlugin { options: [Object] },
     HtmlWebpackPlugin { options: [Object] },
     UglifyJsPlugin { options: [Object] } ],
  module: { loaders: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  postcss: 
   [ { [Function]
       options: [Object],
       info: [Function],
       postcssPlugin: 'autoprefixer',
       postcssVersion: '5.0.14' },
     { [Function: creator] postcss: [Object], process: [Function] } ],
  resolve: 
   { alias: 
      { libs: '/Users/apple/Desktop/WorkSpace/GitHub/Webpack-Boilerplate/dev-config/libs',
        nm: '/Users/apple/Desktop/WorkSpace/GitHub/Webpack-Boilerplate/dev-config/node_modules',
        assets: '/Users/apple/Desktop/WorkSpace/GitHub/Webpack-Boilerplate/dev-config/assets' } },
  externals: { jquery: 'jQuery', pageResponse: 'pageResponse' },
  entry: 
   { index: './src/index.js',
     helloworld: './src/modules/helloworld/container/app.js',
     counter: './src/modules/counter/container/app.js',
     form: './src/modules/form/form.js' } }
```

It is strange that the generated `vendors.bundle.js` chunk is minified, but other chunks are not. The whole project is here: https://github.com/wxyyxc1992/Webpack-React-Redux-Boilerplate, just use `npm run build` to build project and see the dist directory.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles across this later, I found the following which helped me immensely: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/104#issuecomment-358646531

Answer (score 1):

The reason why some chunks aren't getting minified is probably because UglifyJS encountered an error and aborted replacing that chunk. This is a plugin error, which will not cause your compilation to fail (i.e. setting `compiler.options.bail` would have no effect, you would get a compilation that's unminified).

UglifyJS uses it's own AST which supports only ES5 and the problem here may be that you have not transformed all the ES6/next syntax that you use to ES5. I would recommend that you configure UglifyJS with `uglify.verbose = true` and make sure you can see the warning and error log output from the plugin while the compiler is running.

Comment: but while i use the uglifyjs in cmd, for example:uglifyjs --verbose  dist/counter.bundle.js.0285fe1a -o dist/a.min.js it works well

Comment: Still, it would be helpful if you could see the output from UglifyJS and observe that it didn't abort a chunk during minification.